# What are the benefits of a sequential index key, and how much wiggle room do I have?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

Sequential keys allow one to use clustered index.  How material is that benefit?  How much is lost if 1% (say) of the keys are out of sequential order by one or two rank?

Thanks,

JDelage

Comment: Your statement isn't entirely correct. InnoDB, for example, will auto generate hidden clustered index if the table definition doesn't have a suitable candidate for one within its schema so it's going to use one whether you want it or not. I don't really understand what do you mean by how material that is. It basically means that the data is stored at the same row with the index, which makes primary key lookups really fast. Question is, why would you have keys out of (natural) order? That implies you'd be messing with primary keys which isn't really good choice.

Comment: @Michael J.V. - I'm thinking of using `uniqid("",TRUE)`, which adds a randomish postfix to a timestamp.  That means that 2 users who were registering on the same microsecond could end up being entered in the db out of order.

Comment: You can use MySQL's UUID() which is much better choice, but why not use simple auto_increment feature? It's not reliant on time of registration, it's always unique to the row it identifies and it takes up 4 bytes internally (if it's int type).

Comment: I want to generate the userID server side in order to also use it as a salt before hashing the pw, without going to the db.

Comment: Nothing prevents you to have auto_increment column as primary key and UUID() / uniqid() as another unique key. However, if all of this is for providing better salt for pass hashing - it kind of sounds like wrong approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short:**
Clustered index, in general, can be used on anything that is sortable. Sequentiality (no gaps) is **not required** - your records will be maintained in order with common index maintenance principles (only difference is that with clustered index the leafs are big because they hold the data, too).

**Long:**
Good clustering can give you orders of magnitude improvements.

Basically with good clustering you will be reading data very efficiently on any spinning media.

The measure on which you should evaluate if the clustering is good should be done by examining the most common queries (that actually will read data and can not be answered by indexes alone).

So, for example if you have composite natural keys as primary key on which the table is clustered **AND** if you always access the data according to the subset of the key then with simple sequential disk reads you will get answers to your query in the most efficient way.

However, if the most common way to access this data is not according to the natural key (for example the application spends 95% of time looking for last 5 records within the group **AND** the date of update is not part of the clustered index), then you will not be doing sequential reads and your choice of the clustered index might not be the best.

So, all this is at the level of physical implementation - this is where things depend on the usage.

Note:
Today not so relevant, but tomorrow I would expect most DBs to run off the SSDs - where access times are nicer and nicer and with that (random access reads are similar in speed to sequential reads on SSDs) the importance of clustered indexes would diminish.

Comment: Thank you.  So if my PK is a userid that is internally generated but that the queries are generally going to go against a different column (userName, say), then I get no benefits from clustered index on my PK.  Correct?

Comment: That plus the SSD aspect suggest that for a db which is destined to grow slowly the benefit of clustering is limited, which is good to know.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the purpose of the clustered-index.

It may be helpful in some cases, to speed up inserts, but mostly, we use clustered indexes to make queries faster.

Consider the case where you want to read a *range* of keys from a table - this is very common - it's called a range scan.

Range scans on a clustered index are massively better than a range scan on a secondary index (not using a covering index). These are the main case for using clustered indexes. It mostly saves 1 IO operation *per row* in your result. This can be the difference between a query needing, say, 10 IO operations and 1000.

It really is amazing, particularly if you have no blobs and lots of records per page.

If you have no SPECIFIC performance problem that you need to fix, don't worry about it.

But do also remember, that it is possible to make a composite primary key, and that your "unique ID" need not be the whole primary key. A common (very good) technique is to add something which you want to range-scan, as the *FIRST* part of the PK, and add a unique ID (meaningless) afterwards.

So consider the case where you want to scan your table by time - you can make the time the first part of the PK (it is not going to be unique, so it's not enough on its own), and a unique ID the second.

---

Do not however, do premature optimisation. If your database fits in memory (Say 32Gb), you don't care about IO operations. It's never going to do any reads anyway.

Comment: If your database fits in the memory you still do care about I/O operations (as long as you like it to be ACID and it is not a read-only database). Updates will invalidate caches and on a busy system quite often. Having said that the OP might have near-read-only situation.